# Optimization algorithm with combinatorical constraints

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematical-optimization, combinatorics

I have an optimization probem with some combinatorical constraint.

My Problem:
I have a bunch of data on which I train a machine learning model which leads to a model `f` that depends on an input vector `x`. The `x[i]`  are all bigger or equal to zero.

I take the output of this model and plug it into a different function `g` that I wish to minimise with some bounds and constraints.
I know how to solve that numericaly with no problem using my favorite optimizer, I am currently looking into pyswarms or EGO. That is no problem.

My problem enters here:
I do not want all values of `x` to be bigger than zero. For example we look at the first 4 values `x[0],x[1],x[2],x[3]`. I do know that I want at least one of them to be bigger than zero but no more than 3.
That means:

```
x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], allowed
 2.1,    0,    0,    0, yes
 1.5,    0,  1.1,    0, yes
 1.5,  2.1,  2.1,  1.2, no (more than 3 values are bigger than zero)
```

My best solution right now is to brute force it:
I take all allowed possibilities and optimise for those.

In the example I take all combinitations of 1,2 and 3 entries out of the four first entries and solve an optimisation problem for each.

THis brute forcing feels not elegant and can explode pretty quickly in terms of computational time.

Does anyone of you know a way to deal with this in a faster way? 
Or, if I am allowed to dream, maybe there is a python optimizer out there that does so out of the box?

I do not expect to have a full solution, but maybe some pointers in the right direction. THis problem does not feel so esoteric that no one thought about it before, I think I am just missing the correct keywords to search for.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What are you trying to optimize on those first 3 values of `x`? An example might help others to know what to suggest.